# Gantt Chart Lightning (aura)

Tags: css, aura, charts

I am trying to create dependencies between task in Gantt Chart for example finish to start , A task need to finish in order to start another task, We have a object which will tell which task is related to which and the type of dependencies it can have,trying to draw something like this below highlited in red:-

[image]

We have "lightning:progressBar" to show the progress bar, Do we have any such thing to create this dependencies directly which can link two task directly based on the type of dependencies they have?  if we try to draw this dependencies line by line, its difficult because this is a dynamic table and we are not sure about the position of next bar and also the bars in between, Looking for some thought to discuss on this,  what solution approach we can have.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please do not repost questions that have been closed by the community. Instead, edit the existing post to improve it towards our community's format and expectations (see [ask]).